# How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions in Julia?

Tags: julia

How do I see if a file exists without exceptions using Julia? I want to make sure that my program does not crash if for some reason the file I am trying to open is not accessible, has been deleted, or does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two simple ways of doing so.

First:

```
println(isfile("Sphere.jl"))
false
```

This `isfile()` function will simply check if the file exists. Note: if `Sphere.jl` is not in your current file path, you would need to provide the absolute path to get to that file.

Second (more of a trial by fire example):

```
try
    open("Sphere.jl", "w") do s
        println(s, "Hi")
    end
catch
    @warn "Could not open the file to write."
end
```

The second example utilizes the try-catch schema. It is always best for your program to not have to deal with errors so it's recommended that you use `isfile()` unless you have to use try-catch for your use case.

It's worth noting that there may be some cases where the file exists, but writing to it is not possible (i.e. it's locked by the os). In that case, using try-catch is a great option when attempting to write.